# Pivot a dataframe with duplicate values in Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
    snapDate     instance   waitEvent                   AvgWaitInMs
0   2015-Jul-03  XX         gc cr block 3-way               1
1   2015-Jun-29  YY         gc current block 3-way          2
2   2015-Jul-03  YY         gc current block 3-way          1
3   2015-Jun-29  XX         gc current block 3-way          2
4   2015-Jul-01  XX         gc current block 3-way          2
5   2015-Jul-01  YY         gc current block 3-way          2
6   2015-Jul-03  XX         gc current block 3-way          2
7   2015-Jul-03  YY         log file sync                   9
8   2015-Jun-29  XX         log file sync                   8
9   2015-Jul-03  XX         log file sync                   8
10  2015-Jul-01  XX         log file sync                   8
11  2015-Jul-01  YY         log file sync                   9
12  2015-Jun-29  YY         log file sync                   8
```

I need to transform this to

```
snapDate        instance    gc cr block 3-way    gc current block 3-way  log file sync  
2015-Jul-03       XX              1                      Na                  8
2015-Jun-29       YY              Na                     2                   8 
2015-Jul-03       YY              Na                     1                   9
...
```

I tried pivot but it returns an error
dfWaits.pivot(index = 'snapDate', columns = 'waitEvent', values = 'AvgWaitInMs')
Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

The result should be another dataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['snapDate','instance'], columns='waitEvent', values='AvgWaitInMs')

Out[64]:
waitEvent             gc cr block 3-way  gc current block 3-way  log file sync
snapDate    instance
2015-Jul-01 XX                      NaN                       2              8
            YY                      NaN                       2              9
2015-Jul-03 XX                        1                       2              8
            YY                      NaN                       1              9
2015-Jun-29 XX                      NaN                       2              8
            YY                      NaN                       2              8
```

**Data:**

I used the following txt file as input (with `read_csv` from `pandas` to get the data.frame):

```
snapDate;instance;waitEvent;AvgWaitInMs
0;2015-Jul-03;XX;gc cr block 3-way;1
1;2015-Jun-29;YY;gc current block 3-way;2
2;2015-Jul-03;YY;gc current block 3-way;1
3;2015-Jun-29;XX;gc current block 3-way;2
4;2015-Jul-01;XX;gc current block 3-way;2
5;2015-Jul-01;YY;gc current block 3-way;2
6;2015-Jul-03;XX;gc current block 3-way;2
7;2015-Jul-03;YY;log file sync;9
8;2015-Jun-29;XX;log file sync;8
9;2015-Jul-03;XX;log file sync;8
10;2015-Jul-01;XX;log file sync;8
11;2015-Jul-01;YY;log file sync;9
12;2015-Jun-29;YY;log file sync;8
```

Comment: I get DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: it is certainly due to your data...what is the type of your column `AvgWaitInMs`?

Comment: snapDate       object
instance       object
waitEvent      object
AvgWaitInMs    object
dtype: object

Comment: you can check the data, I put them on my side. Actually the OP should provide a reproducible example ;) (like a dict to copy/paste)

Comment: Hi I went ahead and changed the datatype of AvgWaitInMs to int and the pivot worked

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to reshape the dataframe to something similar to what you want. Let me know if you have any additional specific requirements on the resulting dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# ====================================
print(df)

       snapDate instance               waitEvent  AvgWaitInMs
0                                                            
0   2015-Jul-03       XX       gc cr block 3-way            1
1   2015-Jun-29       YY  gc current block 3-way            2
2   2015-Jul-03       YY  gc current block 3-way            1
3   2015-Jun-29       XX  gc current block 3-way            2
4   2015-Jul-01       XX  gc current block 3-way            2
5   2015-Jul-01       YY  gc current block 3-way            2
6   2015-Jul-03       XX  gc current block 3-way            2
7   2015-Jul-03       YY           log file sync            9
8   2015-Jun-29       XX           log file sync            8
9   2015-Jul-03       XX           log file sync            8
10  2015-Jul-01       XX           log file sync            8
11  2015-Jul-01       YY           log file sync            9
12  2015-Jun-29       YY           log file sync            8

# processing
# ====================================
df_temp = df.set_index(['snapDate', 'instance', 'waitEvent']).unstack().fillna(0)

df_temp.columns = df_temp.columns.get_level_values(1).values

df_temp = df_temp.reset_index('instance')

print(df_temp)

            instance  gc cr block 3-way  gc current block 3-way  log file sync
snapDate                                                                      
2015-Jul-01       XX                  0                       2              8
2015-Jul-01       YY                  0                       2              9
2015-Jul-03       XX                  1                       2              8
2015-Jul-03       YY                  0                       1              9
2015-Jun-29       XX                  0                       2              8
2015-Jun-29       YY                  0                       2              8
```

Comment: Almost there is there a way to repeat the snapDate instead of the blanks.

Comment: @jhon.smith sure, just add `.reset_index()`. I've updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Hmm My dataframe had 12 rows but when i tried the unstack operation the resulting dataframe has only 6 rows not exactly what i want.My resulting dataframe should also have 12 rows

Comment: @jhon.smith I don't think you can keep the same number of rows as your original df because some rows have to mov to columns. For example, say `Jul-03` data, row `0, 6, 9` are all records about the same `snapDate` with instance `XX`. So doing a pivot would reshape these 3 rows to only one row because those data have been moved to columns.