# Python Pandas pivot multiple string columns containing duplicate values without aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe and want to pivot it in a way that the column `Imprv_Attribute` is converted into single columns per key and the values should be `Imprv_Attr_Desc`. I need the `Imprv_Attr_Units` information as well, for each newly created column, for example the `Imprv_Attr_Units` of `Bathrooms` should get their own column called `Bathrooms_Imprv_Attr_Units`.

```
|     | Parcel        | Imprv_Attribute | Imprv_Attr_Desc   | Imprv_Attr_Units |
| --- | ------------- | --------------- | ----------------- | ---------------- |
| 0   | 00002-000-000 | Bathrooms       | 2.0-Baths         | 1.0              |
| 1   | 00002-000-000 | Bedrooms        | 2-2 BEDROOMS      | 1.0              |
| 2   | 00002-000-000 | Exterior Wall   | 13-PRE-FAB PANEL  | 100.0            |
| 3   | 00002-000-000 | Floor Cov       | 08-SHEET VINYL    | 20.0             |
| 4   | 00002-000-000 | Floor Cov       | 14-CARPET         | 80.0             |
| 5   | 00011-000-000 | Bathrooms       | 3.0-Baths         | 1.0              |
| 6   | 00011-000-000 | Bedrooms        | 3-3 BEDROOMS      | 1.0              |
| 7   | 00011-000-000 | Exterior Wall   | 15-CONCRETE BLOCK | 60.0             |
| 8   | 00011-000-000 | Exterior Wall   | 20-FACE BRICK     | 40.0             |
| 9   | 00011-000-000 | Floor Cov       | 14-CARPET         | 100.0            |
```

My final result should look like this:

```
| Parcel        | Bathrooms | Bathrooms_Imprv_Attr_Units | Bedrooms     | Bedrooms_Imprv_Attr_Units | Exterior Wall     | Exterior Wall_Imprv_Attr_Units | Floor Cov      | Floor Cov_Imprv_Attr_Unit |
| ------------- | --------- | -------------------------- | ------------ | ------------------------- | ----------------- | ------------------------------ | -------------- | ------------------------- |
| 00002-000-000 | 2.0-Baths | 1.0                        | 2-2 BEDROOMS | 1.0                       | 13-PRE-FAB PANEL  | 100.0                          | 08-SHEET VINYL | 20.0                      |
| 00002-000-000 |           |                            |              |                           |                   |                                | 14-CARPET      | 80.0                      |
| 00011-000-000 | 3.0-Baths | 1.0                        | 3-3 BEDROOMS | 1.0                       | 15-CONCRETE BLOCK | 60.0                           | 14-CARPET      | 100.0                     |
| 00011-000-000 |           |                            |              |                           | 20-FACE BRICK     | 40.0                           |                |                           |
```

So far I [have tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255671/pandas-column-values-to-columns):

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = StringIO(
    """
Parcel;Imprv_Attribute;Imprv_Attr_Desc;Imprv_Attr_Units
00002-000-000;Bathrooms;2.0-Baths;1.0
00002-000-000;Bedrooms; 2-2 BEDROOMS;1.0
00002-000-000;Exterior Wall;13-PRE-FAB PANEL;100.0
00002-000-000;Floor Cov;08-SHEET VINYL;   20.0
00002-000-000;Floor Cov;14-CARPET;80.0
00011-000-000;Bathrooms;3.0-Baths;1.0
00011-000-000;Bedrooms; 3-3 BEDROOMS;1.0
00011-000-000;Exterior Wall;15-CONCRETE BLOCK;60.0
00011-000-000;Exterior Wall;20-FACE BRICK;40.0
00011-000-000;Floor Cov;14-CARPET;100.0
"""
)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";")
df = df.pivot_table(values="Imprv_Attr_Desc", index="Parcel", columns="Imprv_Attribute", aggfunc="first")
print(df)
```

Which results in this dataframe, where I lose the information about `Floor Cov` and `Exterior Wall` due to the aggregation function `first`.

```
| Parcel        | Bathrooms | Bedrooms     | Exterior Wall     | Floor Cov      |
| ------------- | --------- | ------------ | ----------------- | -------------- |
| 00002-000-000 | 2.0-Baths | 2-2 BEDROOMS | 13-PRE-FAB PANEL  | 08-SHEET VINYL |
| 00011-000-000 | 3.0-Baths | 3-3 BEDROOMS | 15-CONCRETE BLOCK | 14-CARPET      |
```

I have also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424981/pivot-a-dataframe-with-duplicate-values-in-index)

```py
df = df.pivot_table(index=[df.index, "Parcel"], columns="Imprv_Attribute", values="Imprv_Attr_Desc")
print(df)
```

Which results in `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. I have also tried a groupby, but this also does not get anywhere near the result I would like:

```py
df_group = df.groupby(["Parcel"])
for key, item in df_group:
    df = df_group.get_group(key)
    df = df.pivot(columns="Imprv_Attribute", values="Imprv_Attr_Desc")
    print(df, "\n\n")
```

```sh
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Imprv_Attribute  Bathrooms      Bedrooms     Exterior Wall       Floor Cov           HC&V     HVAC  Heat System Interior Wall  Num Res Units     Roof Type     Roofing
0                2.0-Baths           NaN               NaN             NaN            NaN      NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
1                      NaN  2-2 BEDROOMS               NaN             NaN            NaN      NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
2                      NaN           NaN  13-PRE-FAB PANEL             NaN            NaN      NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
3                      NaN           NaN               NaN  08-SHEET VINYL            NaN      NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
4                      NaN           NaN               NaN       14-CARPET            NaN      NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
5                      NaN           NaN               NaN             NaN  04-FORCED AIR      NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
6                      NaN           NaN               NaN             NaN            NaN      NaN  04-ELECTRIC           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
7                      NaN           NaN               NaN             NaN            NaN  01-NONE          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
8                      NaN           NaN               NaN             NaN            NaN      NaN          NaN      04-PANEL            NaN           NaN         NaN
9                      NaN           NaN               NaN             NaN            NaN      NaN          NaN           NaN  Num Res Units           NaN         NaN
10                     NaN           NaN               NaN             NaN            NaN      NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN  03-GABLE/HIP         NaN
11                     NaN           NaN               NaN             NaN            NaN      NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN  03-ASPHALT

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Imprv_Attribute  Bathrooms      Bedrooms      Exterior Wall  Floor Cov           HC&V        HVAC  Heat System Interior Wall  Num Res Units     Roof Type     Roofing
12               3.0-Baths           NaN                NaN        NaN            NaN         NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
13                     NaN  3-3 BEDROOMS                NaN        NaN            NaN         NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
14                     NaN           NaN  15-CONCRETE BLOCK        NaN            NaN         NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
15                     NaN           NaN      20-FACE BRICK        NaN            NaN         NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
16                     NaN           NaN                NaN  14-CARPET            NaN         NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
17                     NaN           NaN                NaN        NaN  04-FORCED AIR         NaN          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
18                     NaN           NaN                NaN        NaN            NaN         NaN  04-ELECTRIC           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
19                     NaN           NaN                NaN        NaN            NaN  03-CENTRAL          NaN           NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN
20                     NaN           NaN                NaN        NaN            NaN         NaN          NaN    05-DRYWALL            NaN           NaN         NaN
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) the solution might be a combination of `pd.DataFrame.groupby` and `pd.DataFrame.unstack`, but at the moment I don't know how I can apply these in my case.

If anyone has a good idea on how to help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `pivot_table` ([similar to question 10 in the how to pivot canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)), and a few extra steps.

First you need to create a `cumcount` level so duplicated '`Imprv_Attribute'` values within each `'Parcel'` get their own label you can use to specify the index with. Then aggregate the multiple value columns (with `first`). We'll be left with a MultiIndex on the columns that we collapse by imposing your naming convention in a simple list comprehension. Finally, we can sort the columns and remove the `cumcount` level of the index we created.

```
df['N'] = df.groupby(['Parcel', 'Imprv_Attribute']).cumcount()

df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['Parcel', 'N'], 
                     columns='Imprv_Attribute', 
                     values=['Imprv_Attr_Desc', 'Imprv_Attr_Units'],
                     aggfunc='first')

df1.columns = [x[1] if x[0] == 'Imprv_Attr_Desc' else '_'.join(x[::-1]) for x in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index().drop(columns='N')
```

---

```
          Parcel  Bathrooms  Bathrooms_Imprv_Attr_Units      Bedrooms  Bedrooms_Imprv_Attr_Units      Exterior Wall  Exterior Wall_Imprv_Attr_Units       Floor Cov  Floor Cov_Imprv_Attr_Units
0  00002-000-000  2.0-Baths                         1.0  2-2 BEDROOMS                        1.0   13-PRE-FAB PANEL                           100.0  08-SHEET VINYL                        20.0
1  00002-000-000        NaN                         NaN           NaN                        NaN                NaN                             NaN       14-CARPET                        80.0
2  00011-000-000  3.0-Baths                         1.0  3-3 BEDROOMS                        1.0  15-CONCRETE BLOCK                            60.0       14-CARPET                       100.0
3  00011-000-000        NaN                         NaN           NaN                        NaN      20-FACE BRICK                            40.0             NaN                         NaN
```