# How to pivot and stack dataframe in pandas without group by while having duplicate values in the pivot?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df that looks like this:

```
ref      text   id     
a        zz     12eia
a        yy     radf02
b        aa     a8adf
b        bb     2022a
```

I am trying to rotate this dataframe to look like below with values in column `ref` becoming column names and values in `text` becoming values under those columns and I dont need the 'id' column :

```
a     b     
zz    aa
yy    bb
```

I tried using this line, but I am not getting the result, without adding the `id` column:

```
df_rotated = df.pivot_table(index='ref', values='text', columns='id', aggfunc='first')
```

The data collapses and is not the result I want, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455782/python-pandas-pivot-multiple-string-columns-containing-duplicate-values-without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an appropriate  **index**, which you can do using `groupby` and `.cumcount`.

Here I create the required index:

```
df['ind'] = df.groupby(['ref']).cumcount()
```

Which looks like this:

```
  ref text      id  ind
0   a   zz   12eia    0
1   a   yy  radf02    1
2   b   aa   a8adf    0
3   b   bb   2022a    1
```

You can then create your `df.pivot` as per the following code:

#### Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'ref': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                    'text': ['zz', 'yy', 'aa', 'bb'],
                    'id': ['12eia', 'radf02', 'a8adf', '2022a']})

df['ind'] = df.groupby(['ref']).cumcount()


df_rotated = df.pivot(columns='ref', values='text', index = 'ind').reset_index(drop='true')
print(df_rotated)
```

#### Output:

```
ref   a   b
0    zz  aa
1    yy  bb
```